# How to implement multi select category filter magento 1.8.1 or 1.9 without any extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

i just changed link to checkbox by replace anchor with checkbox in filter.phtml file

```
<span class="check-box"><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onclick='window.location.assign("<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>")'/></span><span class="label"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?><span>
```

Now i only need to filter category by multiple select checkbox in category page.

I try these extension:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html

https://github.com/caciobanu/improved-magento-layered-navigation

lots of free extension but all don't have feature to select multiple category

Comment: You would like to start customizing in Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category::apply() by rewriting it then move on to categories validation methods, and so on.